# Converting date from MS Excel 2010 to R's Date format

Tags: r, chron

With a data set imported from MS Excel 2010, similar to `df` which is:

```
    x0       xx     d1         d2
2014-04-29 16189 1944-04-27 1944-04-29
2014-04-29 16189 1944-04-27 1944-04-29
2014-04-29 16189 1944-04-27 1944-04-29
2014-04-29 16189 1944-04-27 1944-04-29
2014-04-29 16189 1944-04-27 1944-04-29
2014-04-28 16188 1944-04-26 1944-04-28
2014-04-29 16189 1944-04-27 1944-04-29
2014-04-24 16184 1944-04-22 1944-04-24
2014-04-29 16189 1944-04-27 1944-04-29
2014-04-29 16189 1944-04-27 1944-04-29
```

where `xx` is the number of days since 1/1/1900 stored in Excel, and

```
df$d1 = as.Date(df$xx, origin = "1899-12-30") 
df$d2 = as.Date(df$xx, origin = "1900-01-01")
```

as suggested in R Documentation. `x0` is the correct corresponding date generated manually to show what I want to obtain.

How can I convert `df$xx` to R's Date format? With those suggestions, I am not getting the correct year.

Comment: Those dates are in Unix epoch.  Try `as.Date(16189, origin="1970-01-01")`

Comment: How are you getting the data from Excel into R?

Comment: @James I got the data set in Excel format from another person

Comment: @James: the person has the data in MS Access and he exported it to a text file and excel file. I import the text file to R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your values are referencing the Unix Epoch:

```
as.Date(16189,origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2014-04-29"
```