# Issue with reading in Excel file in R

Tags: r, dplyr, readxl, rexcel

I am running into an issue and I don't know how to get through it. I am reading in an excel file in my R code. When I read in the file, the date format in some columns automatically changes into a different format compared to one that is originally in the excel file

As an example I will show you what It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRkOd.png):

```
product_id  tracking_number start_date  end_date
15685       1211343131      5/21/2018   43241
15685       35164164        5/21/2018   43241
24714       5316849643      8/8/2017    43473
27608       4646435131      8/9/2017    43375
27608       531643131       8/9/2017    43375
27659       464641351       8/9/2017    43375
27659       164646131       8/9/2017    43375
38073       1684646131      1/8/2019    43957
```

I want the end_date to be in the similar format as the start_date but for some reason this is what comes up. Can anyone help me with this? I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Can you change the `format` from excel itself

Comment: I tried that but when I read it in R it automatically changes again.

Comment: Usually, I do `format cells`, change it from excel and reload.  If it is not working, then you can do `as.Date(43241, origin = '1899-12-01')#
[1] "2018-04-22"` i.e. in your case, it is `as.Date(df1$end_date, origin = '1899-12-01')`

Comment: Likely dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42757553/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/24574939/3358272. (@akrun, one of those is yours :-)